# Unity не открывается сцена

Tags: c#, android, unity3d

Изменил код, логику нигде не потеряла. Однако теперь сцена не открывается. На этом коде стоит все переходы между сценами.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
using UnityEngine;
using Assets.Scripts;

public class OpenScene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject gameObject;

    private Animator getAnimator()
    {
        gameObject.SetActive(true);
        return gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private RuntimeAnimatorController setController(string controllerName)
    {

        var controller = Resources.Load<RuntimeAnimatorController>($"Animations/Transitions/{controllerName}.controller");
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        controller = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<RuntimeAnimatorController>($"Assets/Animations/Transitions/{controllerName}.controller");
#endif
        return controller;
    }

    private void startScene(string controllerName)
    {
        Animator animator = getAnimator();
        var controller = setController(controllerName);
        startAnimation(animator, controller);
    }

    private void startAnimation(Animator animator, RuntimeAnimatorController controller)
    {
        animator.runtimeAnimatorController = controller;
        animator.SetTrigger("StartAnimation");
    }

    public void startRegistrationScene()
    {
        startScene("GoToRegistration");
    }

    public void startChooseCourpuseScene()
    {
        startScene("GoToChooseCouprose");
    }

    public void startFirstCourposeARExcursion()
    {
        SessionManager.courposeId = 1;
        startScene("GoToCourposeARScene");
    }

    public void startSecondCourposeARExcursion()
    {
        SessionManager.courposeId = 2;
        startScene("GoToCourposeARScene");
    }

    public void startFirstCourposeCabinetsList()
    {
        SessionManager.courposeId = 1;
        startScene("GoToTimeTableScene");
    }

    public void startSecondCourposeCabinetsList()
    {
        SessionManager.courposeId = 2;
        startScene("GoToTimeTableScene");
    }

    public void startCabinetSheduleScene(string cabinetId)
    {
        SessionManager.cabinetNumber = cabinetId;
        startScene("GoToCabinetShedule");
    }

    public void goBackToCabinetslist()
    {
        if (SessionManager.courposeId == 1) 
            startFirstCourposeCabinetsList();
        else
            startSecondCourposeCabinetsList();
    }
}
```

У меня подозрения в том, что юнити не находит контроллеры для переходов. То ли не правильно указал путь к ресурсу, то ли не правильное расширение.
В unity editor всё прекрасно работает, переходит. А на мобильном устройстве после нажатия кнопки всё приложение застывает и не дает нажать на кнопки в экране.

Вот причина по которой считаю, что всё в этом куске кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этот код проходит после успешной авторизации:

```
if (session != null)
{
    registrationError.text = "Начинаю вход";
    gameObject.GetComponent<OpenScene>().startChooseCourpuseScene();
}
```

Текст высвечивается, а после него идет только фрагмент с загрузкой сцены. Где фрагмент "gameObject" становится активным. gameObject - моем случае панель, которая будет потом становится не прозрачной, для анимации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Изначально она не активна, а потом активируется. В OpenScene это видно в этом фрагменте

```
 gameObject.SetActive(true);
```

Из-за него не получается нажать на другие кнопки. Поэтому вывод мой, что ошибка где то, в назначении контроллера и запуске анимации.